# How to change a link pointing to JavaScript to run automatically?

Tags: javascript, html

If I have JavaScript function which is called **only** when I click on a link.

How can I run that JavaScript automatically?

Please note that I've tried many methods, but they are not working.

The code is:

```
<div align="left"><a href="javascript:show_desc(document.getElementById('d_<?php echo $item->id;?>'));" class="tablchet" ><?php echo $item->name;?></span></a></div>
```

Comment: `I've tried many methods but they are not working` - then try some different ones

Comment: I'm assuming when you say "automatically" you want it to run when the page loads.  Have you tried looking at the document's load event, or perhaps better, the $(document).ready() from jQuery?

Comment: Unless you're already using jQuery, using it for this trivial task is overkill. If you want it to run every time, just put it in a script tag in the head section of your page at the outer level. If you don't want it to run until the page has loaded, then follow @jeffcarey's suggestion and attach it to the document's load event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to properly separate presentation (HTML) and behavior (JS) we will not include any JS into HTML markup. We will also not create dependencies between type of tag and JS function so our code will be

```
<div align="left">
    <a href="" data-id="<?php echo $item->id; ?>" class="tablchet">
        <span><?php echo $item->name; ?></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

or even the following

```
<div align="left">
    <span data-id="<?php echo $item->id; ?>" class="tablchet"><?php echo $item->name; ?></span>
</div>
```

For the presentation, it's ok. Now, use some JS into a separate file included after the presentation HTML with `<script src="behavior.js"></script>` or directly into HTML document between `<script></script>`.

The JS could be as following:

```
// Create a function allow you to manipulate the item clicked and the item targeted (with the id).
var showDesc = function (sender, target) {
    // When the sender is clicked...
    sender.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // Do Something with the target...
        console.log(target);
    });
};

// This part will be executed when all HTML presentation from server will be parse.
document.addEventListener("load", function () {
    // Our sender is our `class="tablchet"` markup.
    var sender = document.getElementsByClassName("tablchet")[0],
        // create the id name with the `data-id` information.
        id = "d_" + sender.getAttribute("data-id"),
        // and our target is finded with its id.
        target = document.getElementById(id);

    // Use our showDesc with sender and target wished.
    showDesc(sender, target);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you run the javascript on page is to use the `script` tag.

Your example would look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    show_desc(document.getElementById('d_<?php echo $item->id;?>'));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well,you are `document.getElementById`,So,one thing is clear you want to call method after complete page is load as you get the element after DOM is ready.

With JavaScript you can do like this.

```
window.onload = function() {

    var show_desc = function(htmlEle) {
        // do further processing.
    }

    var eleId = 'd_<?php echo $item->id;?>';
    var htmlEle = document.getElementById(eleId);
    show_desc(htmlEle);
}
```

If you are using jQuery lib then you can do like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    var show_desc = function(htmlEle) {
        // do further processing.
    }
    var eleId = 'd_<?php echo $item->id;?>';
    var htmlEle = $("#eleId");
    show_desc(htmlEle);

})
```